# Good IMAP library for a Mac application

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, imap

I am looking for a nice library that can talk to GMail from a Mac application. Really, I am thinking about writing a GMail application for the Mac. Thunderbird and Mail.app just don't cut it for me.

Anyway, the library should be written in C, C++ or Obj-C or at least have interfaces for those languages. Of course, anything free and/or open source would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You realize that you can use Apple's own Mail application with GMail IMAP, right?  You also realize that GMail IMAP is just IMAP (or POP) and that there's nothing special about GMail's IMAP, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. But GMail does a few things different to your usual email provider (archive, conversations, tags) and I like that. This functionality is replicated somewhat awkwardly in IMAP but that is just why I would want a dedicated application that "understands" GMail IMAP.

Comment: The application you're looking for is called "Safari" or "Chrome" or "Firefox". It has a bar on top, where you enter www.gmail.com and it lets you do everything you possibly can imagine with GMail. New versions of this "Chrome" application can even access GMail when offline.

Comment: @psychotik. For you, maybe. Not for me though. I prefer a native application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [vmime](http://www.vmime.org/) should work for this.